# How to convert P7C file to pem file using PHP7.1?

Tags: php, openssl, certificate

I am dealing with some certificate problems.
I want to convert a p7c file to pem file.
For the safety reason, the system has disable some php functions such as "system, exec" and so on.
But the openssl extension in php is not complete implementation, so I don't how to do it.
Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could ask this question on [servervault](https://serverfault.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

The P7C indicates a [PKCS#7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315.txt) witch is either a signed or encrypted container that can contain almost everything - think of a ZIP file.

[PEM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421) specifies how to format encrypted or authenticated data (for electronic mail). Distilled: The base64 representation of data.

To convert the P7C/[PKCS#7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315.txt) to [PEM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421) format just read the bytes and write them as [base64](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).

If this is not what you intended to do, please rephrase you question and give us some more details...

If your intend was to read certificates encapsulated in the P7C have a look at PHP's [openssl_pkcs7_read](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-read.php) method